# System can not return display after locking

Tags: lock-screen

My Ubuntu 13.10 works great except for one issue. When I lock the system and try to unlock after long time I don not get any display on the screen, no matter what key I hit. Kindly suggest a fix.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try just using suspend mode as that always returns to where you were. Unless you are using the lock function so others can't access your screen.